# Попытался написать функцию по задаче на CodeWars на Python, но она выводит None вместо ожидаемого вывода

Tags: python

Вот так выглядит задача:

Необходимо выполнить функцию / метод двух самых старых возрастов. Он должен принимать в качестве аргумента массив чисел и возвращать два самых высоких числа в массиве. Возвращаемое значение должно быть массивом в формате [второй самый старый возраст, самый старый возраст]. Порядок переданных чисел может быть любым. В массиве всегда будет как минимум 2 элемента. Если есть два или более самых старых возраста, верните их оба в формате массива. Например:

```
two_oldest_ages([1, 3, 10, 0]) # should return [3, 10]
```

Вот так я попытался реализовать эту задачу:

```
def two_oldest_ages(ages):
    #your code here
    two_old_ages = []
    while len(two_old_ages) < 2:
        old_age = max(ages)
        two_old_ages.append(old_age)
        ages.remove(old_age)
    return two_old_ages.reverse()
```

Но эта функция выводит None вместо ожидаемого списка с 2 старыми возрастами. Пожалуйста, можете объяснить в чём проблема?

Comment: `return reversed(two_old_ages)`. Потому как `two_old_ages.reverse()` реверсирует сам список, но ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо)